# FPGA LUTs for combinational logic

Tags: verilog, lookup-tables, register-transfer-level

I'm having trouble finding direct answers to how FPGA-level LUTs are accessed/implemented in simple modules (I'll provide an example below). Referring to the top answer on this post, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163961/creating-a-verilog-code-for-4-bit-multiplier-using-lookup-table, the type of LUT I'm trying to understand is the first one listed (FPGA-level).

For example, let's say I had the following module:

```
module RightRotation
{
  input logic clk
  input logic [2:0] din
  output logic [2:0] dout
};

always@(clk) begin
  dout[0] <= din[2];
  dout[1] <= din[0];
  dout[2] <= din[1];
end
endmodule
```

If I were to implement this module with a FPGA-level LUT with 3 inputs and 1 output, how many lookups would it take (for instance, is a value looked up every time a value is assigned with a nonblocking statement in the always@)? How would this answer change if I had 4, or 5, or 6 inputs?

Comment: the module in your code implement three flops. You do not need any combinational luts for it unless flops are implemented using luts. Also luts usually have 1-bit outputs, so your implementation depends a lot on the number of output bits. All this is a task of an fpga synthesizer tuned up to a particular version of an fpga board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing syntax errors, Vivado produces these results for utilization and implementation.

N inputs would use N flops in your design.

[image]

Vendor datasheets can help understand look up tables, CLBs, slices etc.
Example here:
https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug474_7Series_CLB.pdf